# plotly display legend based on conditional color

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have 2D points, labeled True/False. I want to make a scatter plot, such that True points will be green, False points will be red. In addition, I want a legend in the side to display {green_dot}=True, {red_dot}=False. How can I add such legend?

Here's a minimal example. I have to use go.Scatter(), everything else can be changed.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = np.arange(-3,3)
color = (x>=0).astype('int')
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, 
                           marker=dict(color=color,
                                      colorscale=[[0,'red'],[1,'green']]),                                
                                      showlegend=True))
fig.show()
```

[image]
As can be seen, the legend is not very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your data into a list with the True labelled points and a list with the False labelled points.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
color = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

fig = go.Figure()

trace1 = np.where(color==0)
trace2 = np.where(color==1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x[trace1],
                         y=y[trace1],
                         mode='markers',
                         name='false',
                         marker=dict(color='red')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x[trace2],
                         y=y[trace2],
                         mode='markers',
                         name='true',
                         marker=dict(color='green')
                         ))                         
fig.show()
```

[image]